# SQL - Email sub counts for specific dates (active)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

Hi I received a request to get email subscriber counts by brand via SFMC. Counts on Specific dates (Active ONLY) for these dates 5/29, 7/2, and 7/30. I wrote the below query but am unsure of how to add in the date part to pull only those particular dates...

```
SELECT 
COUNT(SubscriberId) AS NumberOfSubscribers
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY Status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Format function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp) in SQL to convert the date time to the format you want to query.

Assuming you are trying to get the created record count those days in 2022. I would try something like this:

```SQL
SELECT 
COUNT(listSub.SubscriberID) AS NumberOfSubscribers
FROM _ListSubscribers AS listSub
WHERE listSub.Status = 'active'
AND FORMAT(listSub.CreatedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') IN ('05/29/2022', '07/02/2022', '07/30/2022')
GROUP BY listSub.Status
```

Comment: This is coming back with 0 rows... is there any other way to get this data besides a query?

Comment: @Jen The SQL query above was written based on your initial query. If it returned 0 rows, then you would want to check the data again. Let's say if you only query these fields: SubscriberID, CreatedDate, Status from _ListSubscribers data view, do you see any records match with your criteria (e.g. active status and created dates are those dates)?